# What is the significance of Latus Rectum?

Tags: conic-sections

So I just completed the chapter Conic Sections and the one thing I could not understand is what is the use of Latus Rectum?
It is defined as " Line segment passing through the focus and parallel to directrix."
I've done questions like what is the length of latus rectum when *some values* are given.
Is it just a line with no significance? I mean there can be a line in parabola parallel to directrix with say 8 times the focus? Is it any less significant than Latus rectum?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Polar_coordinates for an example of its use.

Comment: @BarryCipra yeah my bad, its through focus

Comment: @BarryCipra done